# Nest Array Swap Problem In React-Hook-Form

Tags: swap, react-hook-form

**Describe the problem**

I have an array within an array and when I make a swap in the items of the parent array.

**To Reproduce**

here is demo example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bouman-t5dcs8?file=/src/App.js)

I inited two elements in parent array. And click Button:[swap section]. It can works well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk4F6.png)

When I click Button:[add section], there have three elements. And then click Button:[swap section],  first parent's childs and second parent's childs don't swap rightly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Yrg.png)

i hope it can swap rightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing a custom `key` while React Hook Form needs the field component to have its own generated `id` to be able to track the field's position.

To achieve your desired behavior, you need to pass `field.id` (`section.id` in your example) to the top field element.

```
{sectionsFields.map((section, sectionIndex) => {
  return (
    <div key={section.id}> // pass the RHF provide field id as the component key instead of refreshSelect + sectionIndex 
      ...
    </div>
  );
})}
```